# pandas.to_dict returns None mixed with nan

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've stumbled upon a minor problem with pandas and it's method to_dict.
I have a table that I'm certain have equal number of identical columns in each row, let's say it looks like that:

```
+----|----|----+
|COL1|COL2|COL3|
+----|----|----+
|VAL1|    |VAL3|
|    |VAL2|VAL3|
|VAL1|VAL2|    |
+----|----|----+
```

When I do `df.to_dict(orient='records')` I get:

```
[{
     "COL1":"VAL1"
     ,"COL2":nan
     ,"COL3":"VAL3"
 }
 ,{
     "COL1":None
     ,"COL2":"VAL2"
     ,"COL3":"VAL3"
 }
 ,{
     "COL1":"VAL1"
     ,"COL2":"VAL2"
     ,"COL3":nan
}]
```

Notice `nan`'s in some columns and `None`'s in other (always the same, there appears to be no `nan` and `None` in same column)

And when I do `json.loads(df.to_json(orient='records'))` i get only `None` and no `nan`'s (which is desired output).

Like this:

```
[{
     "COL1":"VAL1"
     ,"COL2":None
     ,"COL3":"VAL3"
 }
 ,{
     "COL1":None
     ,"COL2":"VAL2"
     ,"COL3":"VAL3"
 }
 ,{
     "COL1":"VAL1"
     ,"COL2":"VAL2"
     ,"COL3":None
}]
```

I would appreciate some explanation as to why it happens and if it can be controlled in some way.

==EDIT==

According to comments it would be better to first replace those `nan`'s with `None`'s, but those `nan`'s are not `np.nan`:

```
>>> a = df.head().ix[0,60]
>>> a
nan
>>> type(a)
<class 'numpy.float64'>
>>> a is np.nan
False
>>> a == np.nan
False
```

Comment: A side note, np.nan does not compare equal. Please see [Working with missing data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#values-considered-missing) warning section.

Comment: Noted. I also found `isna()` function which might do the trick, worth checking. But even tho, `is` orator should do with, unless every `NaN` is instantiated as a separate object. Which seams implausible.

Answer (score 27):

I think you can only [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), it is not possible control in [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
L = [{
     "COL1":"VAL1"
     ,"COL2":np.nan
     ,"COL3":"VAL3"
 }
 ,{
     "COL1":None
     ,"COL2":"VAL2"
     ,"COL3":"VAL3"
 }
 ,{
     "COL1":"VAL1"
     ,"COL2":"VAL2"
     ,"COL3":np.nan
}]

df = pd.DataFrame(L).replace({np.nan:None})
print (df)
   COL1  COL2  COL3
0  VAL1  None  VAL3
1  None  VAL2  VAL3
2  VAL1  VAL2  None

print (df.to_dict(orient='records'))
[{'COL3': 'VAL3', 'COL2': None, 'COL1': 'VAL1'}, 
 {'COL3': 'VAL3', 'COL2': 'VAL2', 'COL1': None}, 
 {'COL3': None, 'COL2': 'VAL2', 'COL1': 'VAL1'}]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work :P
this np.NaN is not equal to what I have in the table (which is strange)

Comment: `VALs` are numeric or `strings` ?

Comment: string - data is loaded from json

Comment: Hmm, problem is in real data or with sample too? What is your version of python and pandas?

Comment: pandas == '0.19.2' python == Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: It is weird, I use same version of python and pandas nad for me it works. :(

Comment: I see your edted question, need for check NaN something else `print (pd.isnull(pd.Series(np.nan)))`

Comment: It outputs True

Comment: Nope, unfortunately no. I even tried:
`>>> a = df.ix[0,60]
>>> a
nan
>>> df.head().replace({a:None})`

Comment: and this `a = df.replace({np.nan:None}).ix[0,60]` ? What is `a` ?

Comment: `>>> a = df.replace({np.nan:None}).ix[0,60]
>>> a
nan
>>> type(a)
<class 'numpy.float64'>`

Comment: Hmmm, and what about `print (df.to_json(orient='records'))` ? - [`to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)

Comment: `>>> print (df.head().ix[:,60].to_json(orient='records'))
[null,null,null,null,null]` ¯\\(°_o)/¯

Comment: Yes, you are right. I find [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-json-writer) - `Note NaN‘s, NaT‘s and None will be converted to null and datetime objects will be converted based on the date_format and date_unit parameters.`. So if replace dont work, use only your solution :(